# Starting COOP with bot in Rocket League

Tags: rocket-league

I would like to start a coop in Exhibition in Rocket League, my friend did join my group but I can't find out how to start a bot game with him, how can I do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Invite him to your party, select Play Online, and select Private Match.